# Merge vectors of different lengths to dynamic matrix

Tags: r, matrix

How can I merge 5 vectors together into one dynamic/flexible matrix?

```
  V1 <- c(13, 31, 54)
  name1 <- c("a", "b2", "c")

  V2 <- c(17, 27, 34, 52)
  name2 <- c("a", "b1", "b2", "c")

  V3  <- c(19, 25, 33, 47, 58, 44)
  name3 <- c("a", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c", "d")

  V4  <- c(13, 29, 35, 56)
  name4 <- c("a", "b1", "b2", "c")

  V5<-c(21, 35, 67, 82, 96)
  name5<-c("d", "c", "b3", "b1", "b2")
```

And create a matrix like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can load the objects into the global environment with `mget` based on the `pattern` of object names i.e. those object names that starts with (`^`) 'V' followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) at the end (`$`) of the string.  Then, append `NA` at the end of each of the list element based on the `max` `lengths` of the `list`

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^V\\d+$'))
t(sapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))))
```

If we need the names as well

```
lst2 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^name\\d+$'))
out <- xtabs(unlist(lst1) ~ rep(seq_along(lst1), lengths(lst1)) + 
         unlist(lst2))
names(dimnames(out)) <- NULL
```

---

Or another option is `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)    
map2_dfr(lst1, lst2, setNames)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#     a    b2     c    b1    b3     d
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    13    31    54    NA    NA    NA
#2    17    34    52    27    NA    NA
#3    19    33    58    25    47    44
#4    13    35    56    29    NA    NA
#5    NA    96    35    82    67    21
```

Comment: I think the first option doesn't give the desired result (not referring to the missing names here). +1 for the second option.

Comment: .. maybe something like `t(mapply(function(x, y) y[match(Reduce(union, lst2), x)], lst2, lst1))`

Comment: @markus thanks.  I was thinking with `Map` option.  The `union` optino is removing the column names for me